If my spellcasting focus has the Reach property, does that extra reach apply for spells such as Inflict Wounds?
Inflict Wounds states

Make a melee spell attack against a creature you can reach.

So if my spellcasting focus is a reach weapon, such as a whip, such that I can make a melee attack at the extra range, would that let allow me to use that spell with the increased range?
If the answer is no, would playing a bugbear count as increased reach for the spell?

I've fully removed your original primary question which was closed as a duplicate and instead focused on your secondary question as that does not appear to be covered by the cited duplicate.

@Pyrotechnical Also a dupe, so I changed the dupe link.

@Pyrotechnical Actually, I've rolled back to the version with two questions and included two dupe links.
